# Как мне получить доступ к файлу не зная точного расположения файла вызова кода

Tags: python

У меня есть функция которую я храню в файле например `fun.py`
Код этой функций мне нужен в разных файла и мне приходится постоянно
создавать копию файла рядом с файлом который я запускаю а после выполнять

```py
from . fun import myfun
```

Директория

```
\project
    \folder1
        fun.py
        run1.py
    \folder2
        fun.py
        run2.py
```

И это крайне неудобно и занимает лишнее место и что бы этого избежать
Я хочу хранить только один файл `fun.py` в папке `\project` и после получать к ниму доступ

Например как здесь

fun.py

```py
def myfun(): 
    print('!!! Hello myfun !!!\n')
```

run.py

```py
import sys
sys.path += [r'C:\project']

from fun import myfun

myfun()
```

Директория

```
\project
    fun.py
    \folder1
        \folder2
            run.py
```

или

```
\project
    fun.py
    \folder1
    \folder2
        run.py
```

позиция run.py может быть любой

Но проблема такого метода в том что как только я перемещу папку `\project` в другое место
мне придется переписывать все пути `sys.path` снова

Как я могу сделать все правильно что бы не переписывать все и не засорять проэкт лишними файлами?

Comment: Так если импортируемый модуль в корне, то должно работать как есть

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял и если `fun.py` запускать из каталога `path/project`, то это может выглядеть примерно так:

**fun.py**

```
import sys
import os


def myfun():                                                    # <---
    print('!!! Hello myfun !!!\n')
    
def passage(file_name, folder):
    for element in os.scandir(folder):
        if element.is_file():
            if element.name == file_name:
                yield folder
        else:
            yield from passage(file_name, element.path)

_path = list(passage('run.py', os.getcwd()))

if _path:
    path_run = _path[0]
    sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(path_run))                 # <---
    import run                                                  # <---
```

**run.py**

```
print('\nHello run.py\n')

from fun import myfun

myfun()                                                        # <---
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Наоборот мне нужно запустить файл run.py, и уже от него получить доступ к fun.py. Я поправил вопрос

Добавьте в папку `path/project` модуль `main.py` и запустите его:

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os

def passage(file_name, folder):
    for element in os.scandir(folder):
        if element.is_file():
            if element.name == file_name:
                yield folder
        else:
            yield from passage(file_name, element.path)

_path = list(passage('run.py', os.getcwd()))

if _path:
    path_run = _path[0]
    sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(path_run))                 # <---
    import run                                                  # <---
```

**run.py**

```
print('\nHello run.py\n')

from fun import myfun

myfun()                                                         # <---
```

**fun.py**

```
def myfun():                                                  # <---
    print('!!! Hello myfun !!!\n')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наоборот мне нужно запустить файл `run.py`, и уже от него получить доступ к `fun.py`. Я поправил вопрос

Comment: @orlatym я добавил второй вариант

Comment: Я уточнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию вы не можете. При импорте файла Python ищет только текущий каталог, каталог, из которого выполняется точка входа script, и sys.path, который включает в себя такие места, как каталог установки пакета (он на самом деле немного сложнее, чем этот, но это охватывает большинство случаев).

Однако вы можете добавить к пути Python во время выполнения(это пример):

## some_file.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Comment: Ответ не мой!!!

Comment: Я знаю про `sys` но я не понимаю как сделать кастомный путь что бы не менять все вручную.
`sys` легко делать если мне нужно запустить `fun.py` и получить доступ к `run.py` но мне нужно наоборот.